# Is this a bijective function from $\mathbb{R}$ to irrational

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Define the set of all irrational by $\mathbb{I}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\mathscr{A}:=\{q+e^n:q\in\mathbb{Q},n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subsetneq\mathbb{I}$

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathscr{A}&\cup\Big(\mathbb{R}\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathscr{A})\Big)\\
\mathbb{I}=\mathscr{A}&\cup(\mathbb{I}\setminus\mathscr{A})
\end{align*}

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ as following

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
q+e & \text{if } x=q\in\mathbb{Q}\\
q+e^{n+1} & \text{if } x=q+e^n\in\mathscr{A},n\geqslant 1\\
x & \text{if } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathscr{A}) 
\end{cases}
$$

Generally, I know the strategy to construct a bijective function for such a subset equinumerous to its superset, not only split out the obvious complement but also another subset to allow recursive mapping happens.

Every time for such questions I am just so unsure if they are bijective.

I've seen a similar post but please help me to check and please leave your comment either right or wrong

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by those two lines after $\subsetneq \mathbb I...$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's my strategy to remind myself to construct the function properly. $\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathscr{A}$ should maps to $\mathscr{A}$ and recursive happens in $\mathscr{A}$. The rest are identity function

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is this function seems to be bijective ?

Comment: Your strategy in a post is to communicate to people who are trying to help you for free. You still haven't said what those lines mean.

Comment: Don't tag people who are trying to understand the question and ask then to answer the question. That's rude. You've already asked the question, you don't need to ask it again.

Comment: The real key is that those are disjoint unions.

Comment: My bad. Has been edited.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes. I partition the set.

Comment: The key is that for each element in $x\in \mathcal A,$ there is a unique pair $q,n$ such that $x=q+e^{n},$ which requires you to show that $e^n-e^m$ is never rational. It's true, but it requires a lot more work than if you choose $$\mathcal A'=\{q+n\sqrt2\mid q\in\mathbb Q, n\in\mathbb N^{\geq1}\}$$

Comment: But you never say it is a partition. You just leave those statements hanging there. Tell us why you are writing stuff. The goal is communication.

Comment: For your case, you need something stronger than "$e$ is irrational." "$e$ is transcentwl" works, but knowing $e$ is transcendental is much trickier, when you really just need one irrational number.

Comment: You could replace $e$ with some number assumed to be transcendental (such much exist by counting arguments) or with a number like $\sum 10^{-n!}$ for which it is easy to prove transcendence.  But I prefer the simpler approach mentioned by @ThomasAndrews  The point here being that the transcendence of $e$ is a deeper result than the one you are aiming to prove.